# AddJsonOptions not found in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm migrating my ASP.NET 1.1 project to 2.0:

Inside the `Setup` class, under the `Configure` method override I have:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter())
    );
```

The `AddJsonOptions` method is missing.

What happened to it? How can I get the same functionality?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have gone anywhere - It works in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 project. It's defined in [`MvcJsonMvcBuilderExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/DependencyInjection/MvcJsonMvcBuilderExtensions.cs).

Comment: it's still there; make sure you're using the right packages and ns, `ctrl + .` is your friend

Comment: Had to still separately add `using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;` depending what you want to do next. In my case I wanted `AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());` but `DefaultContractResolver` is not recognized. Really annoying that you have to magically intuit the requirement for all these damn things in .NET.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`AddJsonOptions` is defined in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json) nuget package.

If your project has a dependency to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` metapackage (in your .csproj: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0"/>` ) then you already have it. Otherwise, you may need to add that package directly.

After that do:

- `dotnet restore`
- check that you have `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`