# services AddJsonOptions .net core 2.1

Tags: .net

Previously with .net 2.0, you can add json stuffs this way

```
 services.AddJsonOptions(options => {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

or

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

I realize I can't do the same thing with .net 2.1.

I get this error:

```
'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddJsonOptions'
and the best extension method overload 'MvcJsonMvcBuilderExtensions.AddJsonOptions(IMvcBuilder, Action<MvcJsonOptions>)' 
requires a receiver of type 'IMvcBuilder
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(.....)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AddJsonOptions not found in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053995/addjsonoptions-not-found-in-asp-net-core-2-0)

Comment: This does not work with .net 2.1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(...)
```

to configure it.

Above extension method can be found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json
Version 2.1.0.0`. Either include this package directly, or add one of these two `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` / `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`.

Comment: This does not work with .net2.1. I tried it earlier.

Comment: Well, this works fine for me. Try a restore using `dotnet restore`. And check your references.

Comment: Okay-- So I have observed that the default mvc was overridden. Now. I've observed that `.AddJsonOptions(...)` with *`ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` added. However, it seems not to have effect since my the code keep throwing ` "Message": "Self referencing loop detected with type 'Lemon.Logic.Models.Customers.Customer'. Path 'Client.Customers[0].Person.Customers'.",
  "Source": "Newtonsoft.Json`*

Comment: Make sure you actually use your customized options. But since i do not know more about your code i cannot help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem - you need to make sure you've got a reference to

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc