# AddJsonOptions for MvcJsonOptions in Asp.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053995/addjsonoptions-not-found-in-asp-net-core-2-0) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064314/services-addjsonoptions-net-core-2-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) about `AddJsonOptions` in older version (2.0 and 2.1 respectively).

I'm Using Asp.net Core 2.2 but there is not such method of `AddJsonOptions` under `services`. I also checked the  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for asp.net core 2.1  where exist the `MvcJsonOptions` and `AddJsonOptions` for Core 2.1 but when changing it to version 2.2 it states there is [no such page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2) for that version.

Does anyone know where is gone this Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064314/services-addjsonoptions-net-core-2-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) `MvcJsonOptions` is moving to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` in Asp.net core 2.2 as it's stated at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1) too and already started to move there for asp.net core 2.1, and also the documentation for Asp.net core 2.2 is not updated yet and that is why we don't see it there.

Comment: Nope. This is not working for me at all in 2.2.0. Also this answer should include the previous answers' solution if you think it is the solution. Not just a link.

Comment: Never mind. This goes on the IServiceCollection, not the AppConfiguration