# .NET Core 3.0 WebApi (JsonSerialize) Does not Serialize Nested Objects/All object information

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a list of object as `IEnumerable<IHit<Header>>`, but .NET Core 3.0 is not emitting all information

this is when I return a single object IHit of the list `obj.ElementAt(0)`

> {"explanation":null,"fields":null,"highlight":{},"id":"123","index":"ky","innerHits":{},"matchedQueries":[],"nested":null, "primaryTerm":null, "routing":null, "score":10.98915, "sequenceNumber":null, "sorts":[],"source":{"timeStamp":"2019-05-16T06:16:07Z", "result":"PASS","testTimeStart":"20190516141559","testTimeEnd":"20190516141607","barcode":"XXRX8762"},"type":"_doc","version":0}

but when I return the list itself:

> [{"explanation":null,"fields":null,"highlight":{},"innerHits":{},"matchedQueries":[],"nested":null,"score":10.98915,"sorts":[]}]

also when I try explicitly to call `JsonSerializer`

```
string s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, typeof(IEnumerable<IHit<Header>>), obj);
```

**To Wrap Up:**

1. **WebApi** is working correctly and returning the object serialized correctly if a **signle** object:

   `public IHit<Header> Get(string id)`

but when a **list**, then it is not.

```
public IEnumerable<IHit<Header>> GetAll()
```

I tried `IEnumerable, IList, List` and all the same result!

2. **JsonSerializer** is working neither with a single object nor with a list

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I still don't know the weird behavior I faced due to emitting a single object while not the case of list.

but here how solved the problem based on [@poke's answer and @NeilMacMullen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/2696230)

1. add package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`
2. in Startup.cs, add

   `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

Comment: I personally find it ridiculous that Microsoft rolls out its half-baked serializer as a default solution for .NET Core 3.0 projects. I mean, It indeed is twice as fast as Newtonsoft, but it comes with the price of having less than half the functionality mutilated.

Comment: As of today, Jun, 2022, I am using dotnet 6,  this is not working.. very frustrated

Comment: @B.W, I have used the code on  .NET Core 3.0, don't know about .NET 6

Answer (score 6):

Add the attribute [JsonInclude] with .Net 6 for it to serialize lists

e.g.

```
   [JsonInclude]
   public List<StaffEarningDetail> EarningDetails;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your are using `Newtonsoft.Json` then do as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        );

    ...
}
```

If you are not using `Newtonsoft.Json` then do as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

   services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(option => option.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 2);

    ...
}
```

For more details : [Related data and serializatione](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've mistakenly written internal set function at ViewModel class properties
as follows;

`public int CampaignServiceFee { get; internal set; }`

just removed the internal keyword so that outside of class, JsonSerializer, can set values.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I mistakenly had a class without `{ get; set; }` present at all!

Answer (score 0):

`JsonSerializer` likely does not know how to serialize `IHit<T>`. I would propose one of:

Getting the JSON `string` response from Elasticsearch, using either

1. the low level client, exposed on the high level client as the `.LowLevel` property. You can serialize a high level request type using `PostData.Serializable(request)`
2. using `OnRequestCompleted()` and setting `DisableDirectStreaming()` on the request or globally on `ConnectionSettings`

or

Mapping the response from Elasticsearch to another type that `JsonSerializer` will serialize.

Comment: thanks I will try this regarding JsonSerializer, but why WebApi is able to return a single object `IHit<Header>` serialized correctly, but when returning the whole list `IEnumerable<IHit<Header>>` then it is not!

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, I'm afraid