# JsonOutputFormatter in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-3.0

In asp.net core 2.2 I used to have the following,

```
  var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
    ContractResolver = new SubstituteNullWithEmptyStringContractResolver()
  };

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonOutputFormatter>();
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new ResponseJsonOutputFormatter(jsonSettings,ArrayPool<char>.Shared));
}

public class ResponseJsonOutputFormatter : JsonOutputFormatter
{
 // Stuff in here
}
```

However in 3.0 using:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
```

and the type `JsonOutputFormatter` is no longer available.

What is the current suggested way of customizing a json response globally?

I tried using `IOutputFormatter` but it doesn't seem to be wired in when I set it within `AddControllersWithViews` as an OutputFormatters so not sure if there are extra steps?

Would middleware with the new endpoint routing be an option? Or is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Related: [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182).

Comment: The up-and-coming replacement to Json.NET, [tag:System.Text.Json], does not currently have a public equivalent to Json.NET's contract resolver.  As such, you may want to stick with Json.NET.

Comment: alternative is `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I personally use Json.NET

- Simply add a package reference to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson).
- Update Startup.ConfigureServices to call AddNewtonsoftJson.

> 

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Json.NET settings can be set in the call to `AddNewtonsoftJson`:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

I am using the default options with compatibility mode

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
             new DefaultContractResolver(); });
```

Reference
  [Migrate from ASP.Net 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: This doesn't work if what you're doing is rewritting the output into a different structure. It only deals with the options of how the format looks.

Comment: Okay... but, how do I add it *globally* though? -- (i.e. OData isn't going to use this; and there is no extension method called `AddNewtonsoftJson` that I can add to the `services.AddOData()` call.)

Answer (score 2):

To revert back to NewtonsoftJson and also configure its output formatter, first add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and then in ConfigureServices you need to call Configure *after* calling `AddController` and `AddNewtonsoftJson`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
    
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter jsonOutputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter>().Single();
        
            // makes changes to the Newtonsoft JSON Output Formatter here.
        });
}
```