# ShouldSerialize method is not triggered in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi

I normally use `ShouldSerialize` to exclude properties that have no data such as array but now, it does not appear to be triggered when I'm only using JSON serializer in `.NET Core 3`. It was being triggered when using `NewtonSoft` but I've removed it from my project since it no longer appears to be required.

For example:

```
    private ICollection<UserDto> _users;

    public ICollection<UserDto> Users
    {
        get => this._users ?? (this._users = new HashSet<UserDto>());
        set => this._users = value;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeUsers()
    {
        return this._users?.Count > 0;
    }
```

Any ideas why ShouldSerializeUsers is not being triggered?

I've seen other answers where you can use:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => { 
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = 
        NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
}
```

But I'd like to know if there is another way to handle this as I'm not using `.AddMvc`

Thanks.

Comment: IIUC, there is no such option in built-in json serializer from `System.Text.Json` namespace, according [sources](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/2b2dd5120029081af767e0eea5e813fd68bded11/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerOptions.cs#L20)

Comment: There is also a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41612) related to possibility to change these options

Comment: You need to revert back to Json.NET to use `ShouldSerializeXXX()` functionality.  To do that see [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I've just tried to revert back to Json.NET but I'm not getting error when it tries to serialize a array of enum as string rather than using a value when using `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter'.` so for now, I'll just have to live with the array being defined in Json even if empty. Not critical right now but would have been nice.

Comment: Well having switched to a different serializer you will need to use the equivalent converter(s) and attributes.  Specifically replace [`JsonStringEnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=netcore-3.1) with [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm).

Comment: Hard to make it an answer since your question doesn't show use of `JsonStringEnumConverter` anywhere.  Absent that, maybe close as a duplicate of [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182)?

Comment: @dbc No, but my original issue is resolved which is to revert back to Json.NET

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that your `ShouldSerialize` is not triggered in ASP.NET Core 3.0 is that, in this and subsequent versions of ASP.NET, **a different JSON serializer is being used by default**, namely [`System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer).  See:

- *[Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)*.
- *[Breaking changes to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in 3.0 #325](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325)*.
- *[The future of JSON in .NET Core 3.0 #90](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/90)*.

Unfortunately as of .NET Core 3.1 this serializer does not support the `ShouldSerializeXXX()` pattern; if it did it would be somewhere in [`JsonSerializer.Write.HandleObject.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.HandleObject.cs#L68) -- but it's not.  The following issues track requests for conditional serialization:

- *[.net core 3.0 system.text.json option for ignoring property at runtime like newstonsoft DefaultContractResolver #42043](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42043)*.
- *[System.Text.Json option to ignore default values in serialization & deserialization #779](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/779)*.

To restore `ShouldSerialize` functionality, you can revert back to using Newtonsoft as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182) to *[Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182)* by [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke), and also *[Add Newtonsoft.Json-based JSON format support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support)*:

1. Install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/).
2. Then call `AddNewtonsoftJson()` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddControllers()
           .AddNewtonsoftJson();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible in Net 5 to use conditional `JsonIgnore`. It does not give you full conditional option, but you can exclude null at least which I suppose is the most used case:

```
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
public string? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

If one wants to allow for optional null in json, it is possible to use a custom `Optional<T>` struct that is similar to `Nullable`, like e.g. [one](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Optional.cs) from Roslyn. Then it's possible to have a value, null, or no field at all in the result JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a ShouldSerialize method not triggered while returning a DTO object from a rest API. The solution I found was to manually convert the object to a JSON string using:

```cs
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    objectToSerialize,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() }
);
```

The ShouldSerialize method is then triggered and if it returns false the corresponding property is hidden in the resulting JSON string. You just need to manually add an HTTP header `Content-Type:application/json` to the response in order to get a similar result.