# Serialization and Deserialization of System.Version using Newtonsoft, dotnet core 2.2 vs dot net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

We need to migrate from dotnet core 2.2 to dotnet core 3.1. We have an object which has a property of class System.Version. We didn't use VersionConverter while serialization and de-serialization with dotnet core 2.2. So the serialized object with dot net core 2.2 had serialized version output in the form `{"Major":2,"Minor":0,"Build":20,"Revision":0,"MajorRevision":0,"MinorRevision":0}` without the use of `VersionConverter`.

With dotnet core 3.1 the default serialization (Without the use of `VersionConverter`) is **2.0.20.0**

We have certain metadata already stored in the former format and other components of the system are also relying on it. Is there a way to continue with the former format for serialization and de-serialization (using newtonsoft) with the new dotnet core version 3.1 ? Currently we want to make the components across the system backward compatible and then onboard to the serialization and de-serialization with `VersionConverter`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666826/where-did-imvcbuilder-addjsonoptions-go-in-net-core-3-0

Comment: We still want to use Newtonsoft.Json for serialization and deserialization

Comment: the main answer there covers how to get it back.

Comment: We are using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(version). This is accessible in both older and recent version. This serialization is giving different outputs for .NET core 2.2 and .NET core 3.1
2.2:`{"Major":2,"Minor":0,"Build":20,"Revision":0,"MajorRevision":0,"MinorRevision":0}`
3.1: `2.0.20.0`

Comment: there must be a converter registered in thye global configuration. you shouldn't depend on that global behavior.

Comment: True we shouldn't depend on that and should have used `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(version, new VersionConverter())`  to begin with. But now that we have landed in this position what is the possible way out.

Comment: You have two options. (1) add the `VersionConverter` to the global configuration and use Newtonsoft globally, or (2) add `VersionConverter` to the local configuration for one call to `SerializeObject`.    It's unclear to me what the issue is.

Comment: Do you want to revert back to [tag:json.net], or use the new [tag:system.text.json]?  In your question you ask, *Is there a way to continue with the former format for serialization and de-serialization (using newtonsoft) with the new dotnet core version 3.1 ?* but in comments you state, *We still want to use Newtonsoft.Json for serialization and deserialization*.  The answer is completely different depending upon what you want.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same de-serialization exception on System.Version types on upgrading from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1.

We created a converter:

```
public class VersionConverter : JsonConverter<Version>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Version value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }

    public override Version ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Version existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, int>>(reader);
        var version = new Version(dict["Major"], dict["Minor"], dict["Build"], dict["Revision"]);

        return version;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

Then we use the converter to de-serialize:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeTypeWithVersionProperty>(serializedValue, new VersionConverter());
```