# newtonsoft.json vs microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.newtonsoft.json - what is the difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

what is the difference between these two libraries?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/
vs
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: See: [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182): *In order to reconfigure your ASP.NET Core 3.0 project with Json.NET, you will need to add a NuGet reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, which is the package that includes all the necessary bits.*

Answer (score 7):

This is an extension to `Newtonsoft JSON`.

See the nuget dependeny list here
[image: json dep]

It appears to connect the Mvc infrastructure of AspNetCore to newtonsofts JSON and extending it by various features.

Answer (score 4):

As @Samuel, said it is just an extension of Newtonsoft JSON. If you check its source repository you will find [classes from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` project using `Newtonsoft.Json`.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/AnnotatedProblemDetails.cs#L6)

Here are the classes from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` source:

[image]

If you want to dig into source code then,

GitHub repository Link: [aspnetcore/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src)