# Json deserialize dynamic does not work in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, json-deserialization

Deserialization of a dynamic object that works fine in .NET Core 2.2, but does not work in .NET Core 3.1.

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package version v12.0.3. It's an ASP.NET Core MVC project.

```
public IActionResult Apply([FromBody]dynamic postData)
{
    string serverPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

    List<ModelData> list = new List<ModelData>();

    foreach (var item in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(postData))
    {
        list.Add(new ModelData
            {
                Key = item.Key,
                Value = item.Value
            });
    }
}
```

I need help to fix it

Input data:

```
ValueKind = String : "[{'Key':'Table','Value':'admins'},{'Key':'MethodValue','Value':'Update'},{'Key':'Page','Value':'1'},{'Key':'Id','Value':'1'},{'Key':'ImgPath','Value':''},{'Key':'Id','Value':'1'},{'Key':'Login','Value':'admin'},{'Key':'Password','Value':'12345678999'}]"
```

It's what I see using debugger

ModelData output

```
public struct ModelData
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }

            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
```

Code from client page

```
function SendFormData(fileName) {
        var jsonArr = "[{'Key':'Table','Value':'@ViewBag.Table'},{'Key':'MethodValue','Value':'@ViewBag.MethodValue'}," +
            "{'Key':'Page','Value':'@ViewBag.Page'},{'Key':'Id','Value':'@ViewBag.Id'},";

        jsonArr += "{'Key':'ImgPath','Value':'" + fileName + "'},";

        var other_data = $("#ApplyForm").serializeArray();
        $.each(other_data, function (_key, input) {
            if (input.name === "Status") {
                return true;
            }
            jsonArr += "{'Key':'" + input.name + "','Value':'" + input.value + "'},";
        });

        jsonArr = jsonArr.slice(0, -1);
        jsonArr += "]";

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/Apply",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonArr),
            async: false,
            success: function (returnUrl) {
                AjaxLoad(returnUrl);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("@Translations.UpsErrorMessage");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: @OmairMajid ValueKind = String : "[{'Key':'Table','Value':'admins'},{'Key':'MethodValue','Value':'Update'},{'Key':'Page','Value':'1'},{'Key':'Id','Value':'1'},{'Key':'ImgPath','Value':''},{'Key':'Id','Value':'1'},{'Key':'Login','Value':'admin'},{'Key':'Password','Value':'12345678999'}]"

Comment: please also add the `ModelData` class

Comment: the string you have is not a JSON. JSON use double quotes `"` for field name and string values, not single quote `'`

Comment: @Pac0 Done it. I added. But in version 2.2 works fine. Version 3.1 don't want to deserialize. Wrote me that I have invalid arguments.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182) to switch your app back to Json.NET from [tag:system.text.json]?

Comment: @Pac0 Yes, thanks!!!!! It's an answer! Need just added right nuget package and add config line to sturtup file.
P.S. ' quote or " quote it doesn't matter, works fine with all :)

Comment: That's not me who gave the last comment, it's @dbc ;)

Comment: @Zicise - glad that helped.  OK to mark this question as a duplicate then?

Answer (score 0):

That seems client fail to send valid postData (no unique), and that is no need to stringify any string variable, except it is an array as following:

```
function SendFormData(fileName) {
    var jsonArr = [{'Key':'Table',''Value':'@ViewBag.Table'},
       {'Key':'MethodValue','Value':'@ViewBag.MethodValue'},
       {'Key':'Page','Value':'@ViewBag.Page'},
       {'Key':'ImgPath','Value':fileName}],
         other_data = $("#ApplyForm").serializeArray();

    $.each(other_data, function (_key, input) {
        if (input.name === "Status") {
            return true;
        }
        jsonArr.push({Key: input.name, Value: input.value});
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Apply",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {postData:JSON.stringify(jsonArr)},
        async: false,
        success: function (returnUrl) {
            AjaxLoad(returnUrl);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("@Translations.UpsErrorMessage");
        }
    });
}
```