# List<JToken> returned as empty array in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I am trying to read a json file and parse it using

```
jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
```

And filtering that array based on some conditions and returning same in ActionREsult OK

```
var categories = jArray.SelectTokens("[*]")
                   .Where(token => (string)token.SelectToken(jPath) == displayLevel);

            return Ok(categories);
```

But on client side I am receiving it as json string with empty array like this

```
[[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]],[[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]]]
```

All this was working before.

Comment: Chances are you recently switched to asp.net-core 3.0 or 3.1.  If so, you're using  `System.Text.Json` instead of Json.NET.  You need to switch back to Json.NET to use `JToken`.  To do that, see [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182).

Comment: yeah we upgraded asp.net identity it got upgraded with that. Let me try doing that.

Comment: Did that solve the problem?

Comment: @dbc yes thanks this helped. So now I explicitly serailize my jtoken when needed, using .net json serialization by default.

Comment: I am having exact issue using aspnetcore 3.1. frustrated for days.