# Although there is Imports Newtonsoft.Json get the error "Type 'JsonSerializerSettings' is not defined."

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I get this error in vb project: 
Error   BC30002 Type 'JsonSerializerSettings' is not defined.
and more similiar errors Although I imported Newtonsoft.Json.
[image]

Comment: Did you just move to [tag:asp.net-core-3.0] or later?  If so it's probably a duplicate of [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182).  As is explained there you need to add a nuget reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`.

Comment: Its asp.net vb project