# JSON deserialization doesn't work on Controller action, but works if done explicitly?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, controller, json-deserialization

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this for me. Normally with all my controller actions, deserialization from JSON to C# objects works just fine, but currently I'm facing an issue where it isn't. Instead of giving the desired result, it gives me a `QBWebhookEventList` object, but the `EventNotifications` List is null.

In the trial and error of trying to fix this, I found that if I change the parameter of my controller action from `QBWebhookEventList eventList` to `[FromBody]JsonElement eventList` then explicitly call the conversion, it works as expected. I'm just trying to figure out what is going on here. I would prefer to not have to do the JsonElement version because it doesn't match any of my other controller actions.

The JSON in question:

```
{
    "eventNotifications": [
        {
            "realmId": "1185883450",
            "dataChangeEvent": {
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Customer",
                        "id": "1",
                        "operation": "Create",
                        "lastUpdated": "2015-10-05T14:42:19-0700"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Vendor",
                        "id": "1",
                        "operation": "Create",
                        "lastUpdated": "2015-10-05T14:42:19-0700"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The C# classes the JSON gets deserialized into:

```
 public class DataChangeEvent
    {
        [JsonProperty("entities", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("operation", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Operation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastUpdated", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventNotification
    {
        [JsonProperty("realmId", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string RealmId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dataChangeEvent", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public DataChangeEvent DataChangeEvent { get; set; }
    }

    public class QBWebhookEventList
    {
        [JsonProperty("eventNotifications", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<EventNotification> EventNotifications { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
 public class QBWebhookController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<QBWebhookController> _logger;
        public QBWebhookController(ILogger<QBWebhookController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Invoice(QBWebhookEventList eventList)
        {
             _logger.LogInformation(eventList.EventNotifications.Count.ToString() + "\nWe Did it!");
//            var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QBWebhookEventList>(eventList.ToString()); This way works if I change the action parameter to [FromBody]JsonElement eventList.

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

**EDIT 1**

Here is my Program.cs file. I did add the option to globally ignore null properties as a commenter suggested.

**EDIT 2**
Added `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` to program.cs.

```
using BusinessLogicLayer.Auxillary;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Auxillary.Interfaces;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.Clover.Interfaces;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.Interfaces;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.Magento;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.Magento.Interfaces;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.Quickbooks.Interfaces;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.SyncServices;
using BusinessLogicLayer.Services.SyncServices.Interfaces;
using DataAccessModule;
using DataAccessModule.Models;
using DataAccessModule.Models.Magento;
using DataAccessModule.Models.Quickbooks;
using DataAccessModule.Repositories;
using DataAccessModule.Repositories.Magento;
using DataAccessModule.Repositories.Quickbooks;
using Flurl.Http;
using Flurl.Http.Configuration;
using InventoryManagement.Hubs;
using InventoryManagement.Models.AutoMapperProfiles;
using InventoryManagment.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using tusdotnet;
using tusdotnet.Helpers;
using tusdotnet.Interfaces;

FlurlHttp.Configure(options =>
{
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
    options.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(jsonSettings);
});

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("InventoryManagmentContextConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<InventoryManagmentContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainDbConnection"), o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery));
    //options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
   
});


builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential 
    // cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    // requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.AddCors();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();


builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<InventoryManagmentContext>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});


// Setup Requirements for Azure AD (User Access Management)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));


builder.Services.AddMvc().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

//IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(types =>
{
    types.AddProfile<ProductProfile>();
    types.AddProfile<CategoryProfile>();
    types.AddProfile<SyncTaskProfile>();
    types.AddProfile<CompanyProfile>();

});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Product>, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Category>, CategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<SyncTask>, SyncTaskRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISyncTaskService, SyncTaskService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Company>, CompanyRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<QBRefreshToken>, QBRefreshTokenRepository>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IQBRepository<QBProduct>, QBProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IQBRepository<QBCategory>, QBCategoryRepository>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMagentoRepository<MagentoProduct>, MagentoProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMagentoRepository<MagentoCategory>, MagentoCategoryRepository>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ISyncTaskCreator, SyncTaskCreator>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICompanyInitService, CompanyInitService>();


builder.Services.AddScoped<QBCompanyService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IQBProductService, QBProductService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IQBCategoryService, QBCategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryDeleteParentAdjustor, CategoryDeleteParentAdjustor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICompanyDeleteCascader, CompanyDeleteCascader>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloverProductService, CloverProductService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloverCategoryService, CloverCategoryService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMagentoProductService, MagentoProductService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMagentoCategoryService, MagentoCategoryService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IExcelFileProcessor, ExcelFileProcessor>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ICloverSyncTaskExecutor, CloverSyncTaskExecutor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IQBSyncTaskExecutor, QBSyncTaskExecutor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMagentoSyncTaskExecutor, MagentoSyncTaskExecutor>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRestockService, RestockService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<ProductImage>, ProductImageRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IImageService, ImageService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMagentoProductImageService, MagentoProductImageService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<BackingItem>, BackingItemRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBackingItemService, BackingItemService>();


builder.Services.AddScoped<ICompanyPruningService, QBCompanyPruningService>();


var app = builder.Build();


app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null;
    return next.Invoke();
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

}
else
{

    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().WithExposedHeaders(CorsHelper.GetExposedHeaders());
});

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();



app.MapTus("/files", async httpContext => new()
{


    // This method is called on each request so different configurations can be returned per user, domain, path etc.
    // Return null to disable tusdotnet for the current request.

    // Where to store data?
    Store = new tusdotnet.Stores.TusDiskStore(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("UploadedFilePath")),
    Events = new()
    {
        // What to do when file is completely uploaded?
        OnFileCompleteAsync = async eventContext =>
        {
            ITusFile file = await eventContext.GetFileAsync();
            Dictionary<string, tusdotnet.Models.Metadata> metadata = await file.GetMetadataAsync(eventContext.CancellationToken);
            Stream content = await file.GetContentAsync(eventContext.CancellationToken);

            using(var fileStream = new FileStream($"{builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("UploadedFilePath")}\\{metadata["filename"].GetString(Encoding.UTF8)}",FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                await content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            await content.DisposeAsync();
            var terminationStore = (ITusTerminationStore)eventContext.Store;
            await terminationStore.DeleteFileAsync(file.Id, eventContext.CancellationToken);
        }
    }
});

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");



app.MapHub<ProgressHub>("/progressHub");


app.Run();
```

Comment: `JsonElement` is from System.Text.Json but `[JsonProperty]` is from Json.NET.  If your controller is using System.Text.Json then Json.NET attributes won't work.  Either replace the Json.NET attributes with equivalent System.Text.Json attributes or revert back to Json.NET as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182) to [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182).

Comment: I get what you're saying, but if that were the issue, then why would JSON Deserialization work in every other controller when using the `[JsonProperty]`? Additionally, the only reason I'm even using the `JsonElement` in this case is because it wasn't fully deserializing properly before, in this controller only.

Comment: We would need to see your `ConfigureServices()` to answer that.

Comment: @dbc I added it to the post.

Comment: what is `FlurlHttp`?  Is it [FlurlHttp.cs](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/dev/src/Flurl.Http/FlurlHttp.cs) from https://flurl.dev/?

Comment: Yes it is. I use it in my data access layer to interact with REST APIs

Comment: I don't see a call to `AddNewtonsoftJson()` like the one shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support-2).  Instead you're calling `.AddJsonOptions()` which configures System.Text.Json not Json.NET, so you must be using System.Text.Json.

Comment: @dbc I changed it and added the stated method, but the issue remains exactly the same.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I don't know what the problem might be.

Comment: @Mister_Kweh You should select what do you want Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json before you posted the question. If you jump from one to another your code will never be working,

Answer (score 0):

Controller action depends on how do you request,  but if [FromBody] works for JsonElement, it will work for the custom class too

```
  public IActionResult Invoice([FromBody]QBWebhookEventList eventList)
```

and I can assume that your controller uses Text.Json if it can deserialize JsonElement, so ALL your properties of ALL your classes should be like  this - replace JsonProperty with JsonPropertyName

```
 public class QBWebhookEventList
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("eventNotifications")]
        public List<EventNotification> EventNotifications { get; set; }
    }
```

also NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore is obsolete, so you can add it in your startup like this

```
 services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(option =>
           {
               option.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = 
               JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
           });
```

Comment: When using `[FromBody]QBWebhookEventList eventList`, eventList is always null.

Comment: @Mister_Kweh Read the second part of my answer and replace PropertyName